# Why I have different CheckBox styles in activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-styles, android-checkbox

I have two ListViews in my application. One i have direct in layout (in activity) and other one is in dialog. Both using own layout, with CheckBoxes.
My problem is, that I cannot make, that checboxes to be same look, I try to define style for each checkbox, but nothing happens.
To see what I mean, please see picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bJSW.jpg) 
How can I make same checkboxes, I wish to have like this in dialog (left  on picture)?

Comment: Are you using different themes for the dialog?

Comment: No, I didn't set anything. For dialog i use DialogFragement.

Comment: I gave up. I create a selector with images as I want and bind it on CheckBox.